# How to Fix Laravel Email Issue

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, swiftmailer, laravel-5.8

I'm implementing Laravel 5.8 built-in Email Verification feature but unfortunately I couldn't figure the bug.

I've added the `MustVerifyEmail` interface in ,y `User` Model.

This is my `.ENV` file in Laravel. Same configuration I used in `mail.php`.

**.env**

```
MAIL_DRIVER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=smtp.gmail.com
MAIL_PORT=465
MAIL_USERNAME="<My user Name>"
MAIL_PASSWORD="<My Password>"
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=ssl
```

[image: Laravel Output]

Comment: As explained in https://stackoverflow.com/a/2748837/2602434 try ssl://smtp.gmail.com

Comment: I made mistake in mail.php file.replaced 'username' => env('my_usr_name') to 'username' =>'my_usr_name'

Answer (score 0):

You have to enable access to less secure apps in your google account security settings.

Comment: Ah ok. Try this: ```MAIL_HOST=smtp.googlemail.com``` and clear the cache. And also can it be that this route is accidentally behind auth middleware?

Comment: No. It isn't helping. I've cleared cache and changed host

Answer (score 0):

For configuring gmail settings in laravel,

```
MAIL_DRIVER=sendmail
MAIL_HOST=smtp.gmail.com
MAIL_PORT=587
MAIL_USERNAME=your_email_address@gmail.com
MAIL_PASSWORD=your_gmail_address_password
MAIL_FROM_ADDRESS=your_email_address@gmail.com
MAIL_FROM_NAME="YOUR_USER_NAME"
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=tls
```

Also update the following in mail.php

```
'pretend' => false,
    'stream' => [
        'ssl' => [
            'allow_self_signed' => true,
            'verify_peer' => false,
            'verify_peer_name' => false,
        ],
    ],
```

To test your configuration put this code on api.php

```
Route::get('/emailTest',function(){

    $emailData = [
        'from'      => 'admin_email@gmail.com',
        'email'     => 'user_email@gmail.com',
        'password'  => 'user_password',
    ];
    // "mails.toUser" : this is my email template in resources
    Mail::send('mails.toAdmin',['emailData' => $emailData],function($message) use ($emailData){
        $message->to($emailData['email'])
            ->from($emailData['from'])
            ->subject('New User Registration');
    });
});
```